# C programming in linux:

Tags: c, linux

From windows, i start programming C language using linux.

My problem is how do i stop or reset the computation.

Like here:(example)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main(){
    int average;
    int total;
    int number;
    int loopcount;
    loopcount=0;
    system("clear");
    while(loopcount<3){
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        total=total+number;
        loopcount=loopcount+1;
    }
    average=total/3;
    printf("the average is %d", average);
    getch();
}
```

Output:
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 1
the average is 1. But when i run it again, the last computed average is added to my new average. How or what should I put in my code to stop this.

? 
I have tried google but can't find the exact keyword for this.
Tnx!

Comment: The average (by which I assume you mean arithmetic mean) of 3 integers is usually not an integer.  You should consider `double average;` and `average = (double)total / loopcount;`

Comment: When i enter 3 numbers(any numbers) the average of this is added to the last average computed. Now my average is 102 even if i entered one(1) as the 3 numbers to be computed.

Comment: I'm wondering how you use `getch` function on *Linux*?!

Comment: i make a header file conio.h sir.

Answer (score 5):

`total` is uninitialized, and so its initial value in unspecified.

Initializing it to 0 will probably resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `total` - you have to assign `0` yourself in `main` function (because the variable is located on stack).

But there is a lot of smell in your code -  I would rewrite it as the following.

Note also removed `conio.h` include, it's not supported in Linux compilers as it is non-standard extension in MS and some other compilers!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    system("clear");
    int total = 0;
    for (int loopcount = 0; loopcount < 3; ++loopcount) {
        int number;
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        total += number;
    }
    int average = total  / 3;
    printf("the average is %d", average);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Also note rounding error when `total` is not divisible by 3 - `int` division returns `integers`

edit: if you want to compile it in plain old C89 you should replace

```
for (int loopcount = 0; loopcount < 3; ++loopcount) {
```

To

```
int loopcount;
for (loopcount = 0; loopcount < 3; ++loopcount) {
```

Or if you prefer newer C99 or better C11 compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` compiler option.

Comment: but if I do NOT init `total` and it is `int` type, does compiler treat it like 0 (`gcc` for example)?

Comment: @HowChen: No, it doesn't. (unless it is in file scope, which it isn't)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Everything could be there and usually there is some garbage

Comment: awesome.c: In function ‘main’:
awesome.c:7:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
awesome.c:7:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: @JustStarted, compile your code with -std=c99 flag as your compiler says to you.

Comment: Or watch my edit - replace one line and it will work even without changing the flag

Comment: Tnx for the edit.No more error. I can use getch in linux by making a conio header. :)

Comment: @JustStarted, although your solution with custom conio header works it is much better to replace `getch` calls with `getchar` calls

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing total to zero before using it in a computation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main(){
    int average;
    int total;
    int number;
    int loopcount;
    loopcount=0;

    total = 0;  /* Added */

    system("clear");
    while(loopcount<3){
        printf("Enter a number:");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        total=total+number;
        loopcount=loopcount+1;
    }
    average=total/3;
    printf("the average is %d", average);
    getch();
}
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I have this in my mind. but didnt do it. Lesson learned.  Tnx Bob!